# Can regex find patterns like this?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am learning more and more about regex and while reading about it I was wondering if regex can do something like this. Looking in a string for, for example numbers that are 3 digits long, where the second digit is 2 higher than the first digit, and the third digit is 4 higher than the  second digit.

For example:

Matches:
137,
248,
359

Would regex be capable of such thing? From my limited knowdlege it does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is only capable of matching string, not performing mathematcial logic on numbers, so it is not able to determine that two digits differ by certain quantity.

So answer is no.

BUT, that rule limits 3-digit numbers to a few, so you can write regex alternation to do that:

```
(?:137|248|359)
```

Explanation:

`(?:...)` - non-cpaturing group

`|` - alternation

Comment: Thanks I knew about that, I was just trying to find out if there is any way to use logic in the matches. It seems there is not.